# Nested set and simple way to insert record

Tags: yii

Im creating form that inserts new set in db. And inserts it under the given parent id.

Im now in `beforeSave()` where I want other db entries to be updated.

```
protected function beforeSave()
{
    if (parent::beforeSave()){

            if($this->parent_id >= 0){
                $parent = self::model()->findByPk($this->parent_id);


                if($parent){
                    self::model()->updateAll(); // cant figure out how to use this as I need.


                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

I think update all would be appropriate function here, but I need it to update every db entry

```
update `nodes` where left > $parent->left to left = left + 2

update `nodes` where right > $parent->right to right = right + 2
```

Here is CActiveRecord updateAll() reference:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#updateAll-detail

I want to do this not making many function calls. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
self::model()->updateAll(array(
    'left'=>$this->left+2,
),'left>:pleft',array(":pleft"=>$parent->left));
```

And

```
self::model()->updateAll(array(
    'right'=>$this->right+2
),'right>:pright',array(":pright"=>$parent->right));
```

If `$this->right` and `$this->left` are independent, you can use `updateCounter()` method like below:

```
self::model()->updateCounters(
    array('right'=>2), //increments +2
    'right>:pright',array(":pright"=>$parent->right)
);
```

Above code, updates all rows(`WHERE right > parent.right`) and increments all rights by 2.

Comment: $parent has $parent->left, $parent->right. You are using $this->left and $this->right that is from CActiveReocord with will be inserted those values are unknown yet.

Comment: I assumed that as a relation.

Comment: as well I need to increment all lefts and rights by 2 to those db entries that left and right is bigger than left and right.

Comment: it's not clear, `'left>:pleft',array(':pleft'=>$parent->left)` means `WHERE left>parent.left`, don't you want this?

Comment: Yes and if `WHERE left>parent.left` is true then increment left by 2.

Comment: @Cirvis ow, this is confusing, if you want to increment values independent of `$this->left` and `$this->right`, take a look at my update

Comment: This is sql error that I get:  CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '>'1'' at line 1. The SQL statement executed was: UPDATE `test_nested_set` SET `left`=:yp0 WHERE left>:pleft